# Fetch parent table rows whose related children ALL match a given criteria?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with `date_created` columns and a foreign key relation:

```
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I need to fetch **only** the parents whose children *all* have a `date_created` of less than January of this year.

My first thought was to use the distinct `parent_id` from all children matching this criteria:

```
select distinct parent_id
from child
where date_created < '2015-01-01'
```

Problem is, this also returns parents with children *outside* the criteria:

```
select id, date_created
from child
where parent_id in (
  select distinct parent_id
  from child
  where date_created < '2015-01-01'
) and date_created >= '2015-01-01'
-- 22 rows returned
```

Comment: Um, maybe you just need a large cup of coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is selected all parents who have children created before 2015-01-01, and no parents that have children created after 2015-01-01.

I removed the last line of your `WHERE` clause that read `and date_created >= '2015-01-01'`.

Here is the query:

```
select p1.id, p1.date_created
from parent p1 
where exists
(
  select 1 
  from child c1
  where 1=1
  And c1.parentId = p1.id
  And c1.date_created < '2015-01-01'
)
And Not Exists
(
  select 1 
  from child c2
  where 1=1
  And c2.parentId = p1.id
  And c2.date_created > '2015-01-01'
)
```

Also, I think you should use either a `JOIN` or an `EXISTS` instead of `IN` or `NOT IN`.  Here is an interesting thread on this topic:

[NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)